# ¿Cómo seleccionar el registro más restrictivo de una tabla?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla `textos` con los campos `libro`, `autor`, `comentarios`, `fecha` y `texto`. La tabla no tiene `PK` y dadas unas variables necesito averiguar el registro más restrictivo de la tabla.

Por ejemplo dadas estas variables:

```
v_libro = 'Vida';
v_autor = 'Martin';
v_fecha = '29/12/1995';
v_comentarios = 'NO_COMENT';


LIBRO   AUTOR   COMENTARIOS FECHA TEXTO
'Vida' |'Martín'|'NO_COMENT'|     |'NO TEXT'
'Vida' |'Martín'|           |     |'NO TEXT'`
```

En este caso tendría que hacer una select que me devolviera el primer registro, y no sabría muy bien como hacerlo.. en caso de que hubiera un registro con el campo fecha alimentado y fuera igual que la variable dada tendría que obtener ese registro..

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que contemplar los casos nulos usando `nvl` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM TEXTOS
WHERE NVL(LIBRO, V_LIBRO) = V_LIBRO
   AND NVL(AUTO, V_AUTOR) = V_AUTOR
   AND NVL(COMENTARIOS,V_COMENTARIOS) = V_COMENTARIOS
   AND NVL(FECHA,V_FECHA) = V_FECHA
```

Answer (score 0):

Soy bastante principiante en Oracle, calculo que debería tener alguna solución que se adapte mejor a la búsqueda que quieres hacer, sin embargo con `sql` básico podrías construir la relevancia para cada fila encontrada, de manera que las más relevantes serían aquellas cuyas columnas que tienen más coincidencias, podrías incluso si lo quieres darle mayor peso a ciertas columnas que a otras. Para armar este valor, simplemente podrías hacer esto:

```
CASE WHEN LIBRO = 'Vida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN AUTOR = 'Martin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN FECHA = TO_DATE('1995/12/29', 'YYYY/MM/DD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN COMENTARIOS = 'NO_COMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Relevancia
```

Es decir si la columna coincide con el valor buscado le daremos un peso de 1 sino 0, la suma de todos los datos buscados nos dará la relevancia de la fila. Aquí si quieres podrías llegar a establecer si por ejemplo una coincidencia en el nombre del libro tiene mayor valor que por ejemplo la fecha, simplemente aumentando el peso.

El filtro de búsqueda obviamente debiera usar un `OR` para cada dato buscado y una vez obtenida la relevancia, ordenar las filas de mayor a menor, de esta forma podríamos quedarnos con la primera de las filas, la de mayor nivel de coincidencia.

La idea final sería algo así:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT LIBRO, AUTOR, FECHA, COMENTARIOS, 
                CASE WHEN LIBRO = 'Vida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN AUTOR = 'Martin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN FECHA = TO_DATE('1995/12/29', 'YYYY/MM/DD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN COMENTARIOS = 'NO_COMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Relevancia
                FROM textos
                WHERE LIBRO = 'Vida'
                      OR  AUTOR = 'Martin'
                      OR  FECHA = TO_DATE('1995/12/29', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                      OR  COMENTARIOS = 'NO_COMENT'
                ORDER BY RELEVANCIA DESC
          )
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Por último:

- Nuestra consulta la incorporamos como subconsulta para poder limitar la salida al primer registro usando `ROWNUM = 1`
- Solo quedaría reemplazar los valores literales por variables, escribí los valores de forma literal ya que fue la única forma que me funciono dentro de este [fiddle](http://rextester.com/NZHZJ53764).